# Scala Play 2.3 InteliJ 14 *community edition - is it possible to run project without cmd line activator command

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compilation, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

From http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/28/a-new-way-to-compile/ I understand that Intellij is using sbt to build - so thats 1x build

At the moment I run a separate command line task to run my project -

```
./activator -jvm-debug 5000 -Dhttp.port=9000
```

So each code change gets compiled twice (once by InteliJ; once by activator)

Is there a way to use the InteliJ build artifacts when I run, so the code is only compiled once?

Is using the Terminal window in InteliJ any different from a normal terminal window?

The versions I'm at are:

Java 7
Play framework 2.3.4
SBT 0.13.1
InteliJ 14 (community edition)

Thanks
Brent

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's definitelly possible.

Install **Play 2.x** plugin (with dependencies) and add the run configuration dedicated for Play 2 (**note** [in Intellij 14 Play2 support is combined within the Scala plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/play-framework-2-x.html))

**Menu** > **Run** > **Edit configurations...** > **Add new configuration** (plus icon in the corner) > **Play 2 App**

After saving you will be able to run your app (also in debug mode) within IntelliJ - i.e. via

**Menu** > **Run** > **Debug 'Your Project'**

btw, you can remove Make (before launch) from there, SBT should handle builds properly without Idea's support

See sample shot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer

From http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/getting-started-with-play-20-in-intellij-idea-12/

Play 2.0 ... is supported in Ultimate edition only.

I'm on community; so I think that explains why I can't get it working

Comment: I don't see how I can avoid "double" compilation if I'm using InteliJ and activator from a separate command. I've updated my question to try be more precise on where I think the double compilation is coming from

Comment: Could you share the steps how to do that?

Comment: (as of march2015) the help section states: "Note that for the IntelliJ IDEA version 14.0 , the Play 2.x framework is merged with the Scala plugin." see : https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/play-framework-2-x.html' **Is this answer still valid?** can you pls update it?

Comment: @Zortkun you can edit answers as well ;) thx for tip, added info to the answer