# Getting started with play-java and IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have been working with the Play! Framework for a few years now, but am still on 1.2.x as I was using the Java and Scala flavour and converting the project would take some significant effort.

I need to do a small project now however and wanted to try Play 2.x. So I downloaded 'activator' and setup a new project (template play-java, not play-scala) and imported it into IDEA. But how do I setup the run and debug configurations? I cannot find any info on this when using Java. I don't have an option in the contextual menu to run as Play as seems to be suggested in the documentation. I do have the Scala plugin installed, and according to the documentation is there no separate Play plugin anymore.

I must be making a simple mistake somewhere, but cannot find where. I can try to configure IDEA as per my settings on the 1.x framework, but don't know if that is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ ? community or commercial ? Did you install required plugins ? Did you follow steps I described yesterday ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27798787/1066240

Comment: Thanks, I didn't spot that post. I have IDE Community Edition, 14.0.2. I have the Scala Plugin installed, but there is no Play 2.x plugin in the repos. Should I get it somewhere else? There is a comment that it is not included in the Community edition, so that could explain it then.

Comment: It works perfectly with the Ultimate Edition, I took the 30-day trail, and will have a look and see how that goes!

Comment: In Ultimate it works (almost) great, can't imagine Play development without this support

Comment: Would you like to put in the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ Idea support Play 2.x very well, unfortunately you need to use Ultimate (commercial) edition for this.